# Drawing a line chart on a canvas while containing div faded out. Then fading in again

Tags: javascript, ajax, charts, coffeescript, chart.js

I have a situation where I'm using the chart.js library to draw a chart on a canvas inbetween 'slide transitions'. During a 'transition' I fade it's container div (i.e. not the canvas itself) out replace it's html with html received from a server which contains a new canvas element, I draw the canvas, then fade back in.

The problem exists when I fade back in. The canvas is blank. If I wait for the the fade in to complete before drawing the canvas, it works, albeit a number of milliseconds after the content has been displayed.

I originally tried to trigger an event when after the "new Chart" statement, but that didn't seem to help things.

The code looks like this: (the version that renders the chart after the fade in)

Is there a way I can actually write the chart before fading in and have it not be blank?

```
class window.SlideManager                                                                                                                                                                     
  constructor: ($content, canvas) ->                                                                                                                                                          
    @contentDiv = $content                                                                                                                                                                    
    @analyticsCanvas = canvas                                                                                                                                                                 
    @currentSlide = 0                                                                                                                                                                         
    @slides = @contentDiv.data('slides')                                                                                                                                                      

  nextSlide: ->                                                                                                                                                                               
    @currentSlide += 1                                                                                                                                                                        
    slide = @slides[@currentSlide]                                                                                                                                                            
    if slide?                                                                                                                                                                                 
      this.renderSlide(slide)                                                                                                                                                                 
    else                                                                                                                                                                                      
      @currentSlide = 0                                                                                                                                                                       
      this.renderSlide(@slides[@currentSlide])                                                                                                                                                

  renderSlide: (slide) ->                                                                                                                                                                     
    $.get(slide, {nolayout: 'true'}, this.handleServerResponse.bind(this))                                                                                                                    

  handleServerResponse: (data) ->                                                                                                                                                             
    @contentDiv.fadeOut(1500,                                                                                                                                                                 
      =>                                                                                                                                                                                      
        @contentDiv.html(data)                                                                                                                                                                
        $(@analyticsCanvas).prop                                                                                                                                                              
          height: 400                                                                                                                                                                         

        @contentDiv.fadeIn(1000,                                                                                                                                                              
          =>                                                                                                                                                                                  
            window.setupCanvas($(@analyticsCanvas), window.createChartData(window.getVisitCounts($(@analyticsCanvas))))                                                                       
        )                                                                                                                                                                                     
    )
```

setupCanvas is what actually draws the canvas, here is its' implimentation:

```
window.setupCanvas = ($canvas, data) ->                                                                                                                                                       
  newWidth = $canvas.parent().width()                                                                                                                                                         

  $canvas.prop                                                                                                                                                                                
    width: newWidth                                                                                                                                                                           
    height: 400                                                                                                                                                                               

  options = {                                                                                                                                                                                 
    scaleOverride: true,                                                                                                                                                                      
    scaleSteps: 10,                                                                                                                                                                           
    scaleStepWidth: Math.ceil(Math.max.apply( Math, data.datasets[0].data) / 10),                                                                                                             
    scaleStartValue: 0                                                                                                                                                                        
  }                                                                                                                                                                                           

  ctx = $canvas.get(0).getContext("2d")                                                                                                                                                       
  new Chart(ctx).Line(data, options)
```

And the instance of the Slideshow manager looks like this:

```
$ ->                                                                                                                                                                                          
  manager = new SlideManager($('#main-content'), '#analytics-canvas')                                                                                                                         
  manager.nextSlide()                                                                                                                                                                         

  setInterval(                                                                                                                                                                                
    ->                                                                                                                                                                                        
      manager.nextSlide()                                                                                                                                                                     
    8000                                                                                                                                                                                      
  )
```

Comment: FYI, `this.renderSlide` could be `@renderSlide`.

Comment: Also, why does all of your code have a million spaces after each line??